# Report builder Aggregate function with power bi dataset

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, reportbuilder3.0

I'm trying to recreate a power bi report (Power BI Desktop) in Power Bi Report Builder where I'm using a non-additive measure. I have read that I can use Report Builder's Aggregate function to move the aggregation to the server side and this way use my DAX measure from the model but I fail to get the same result as I get in Power BI.

My test data table in Power BI (named 'Table'):

[image]

My measure:

`Measure = SUMX(SUMMARIZE('Table', 'Table'[Step], "X", AVERAGE('Table'[sec])), [X])`

Matrix report create in Power BI:

[image]
[image]

After I publish the report to MyWorkspace in Power BI online I can add a connection to it in Report Builder and create a dataset with a DAX query (using Query Designer):

[image]

The resulting DAX query is this:

`EVALUATE SUMMARIZECOLUMNS('Table'[Date], 'Table'[Step], 'Table'[sec], "Measure", [Measure])`

The by using the New Matrix wizard I can crate a Tablix like this:
[image]

I'm expecting to get the same result as I got in Power BI Desktop, but I get the following:
[image]

Can Aggregate be used here or is there another way to calculate a Power BI models measures value for each cell of a Report Builder Tablix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by changing the query language in Query Designer from DAX to MDX.

[image]

Now the result in the "Measure" columns are as expected.

[image]